# Options passed to a path inside insert path style

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

Is there a way to give to the `\path` (inside `mypath` style) the options given to the `\draw` and `\fill` commands (ideally, the path should be drawn and red then filled and blue) ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{%
  mypath/.style = {%
    insert path = {%
      \pgfextra{%
        \pgfinterruptpath
          % This is the path that should receive the options
          \path (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red,mypath];
  \fill[blue,mypath];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess you don't want to give options to the `mypath` style with `mypath={draw=red,fill=blue}` etc. right?

Comment: @percusse Yes `:)`

Comment: Do you really need to interrupt the path? I guess without that should work: `\tikzset{%
  mypath/.style = {%
    insert path = {%
         % This is the path that should receive the options
          (0,0) rectangle (1,1)       
    }
  }
}`.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino You're right. But in my use case, I need to interrupt the path...

Comment: My instinctive reaction is that this is going to be *hard*.  Basically, for each stylistic option that you want to apply to the inner path then you're going to have to copy it across.  One problem is that some styles take effect immediately while others are delayed.  Moreover, `\path` makes sure that it clears everything at the start.  So you'll have to save the effect of each option (and each will be different) and then reapply them to `\path`.

Comment: @AndrewStacey Hum, that's what I feared too. In practical, I'll need only a few options: draw/fill color, draw/fill opacity, draw/fill "status". Unless someone comes with a general solution, I may refocus the question on this more simple problem.

Comment: I think it would be a good idea if you listed the "must have" style options.  You could phrase the question in such a way that a more general solution is still obviously the best one but that a solution that works for a certain list is a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure this is wise, but it shouldn't break anything. In this case, you just need to save `\tikz@mode` and `\tikz@options`, before starting the new path.

You could look at `tikz.code.tex` and find which keys/styles use `\tikz@addoption` and `\tikz@addmode` (or just experiment with options) to find out some of the other things can be passed to the "inner path". I think some transformations could be done as well (if they use `\tikz@addtransform`). I guess any thing that is stored rather than applied straight away is a candidate for this sort of thing.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{%
  mypath/.style = {%
    insert path = {%
      \pgfextra{%
        \let\tikz@mode@save=\tikz@mode
        \let\tikz@options@save=\tikz@options%
        \pgfinterruptpath
          % This is the path that should receive the options
          \path \pgfextra{\let\tikz@mode=\tikz@mode@save\let\tikz@options=\tikz@options@save}
            (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
        \endpgfinterruptpath
      }
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[red, line width=2pt, line join=round, mypath];
  \fill[blue,mypath];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As pointed out, `mypath` has to come last in the options. To get around this problem properly is in principle quite simple and only involves a small number of changes, but would still require pasting in huge swathes of code here. So a simple, and unwisely crude approach is to add an `at end path` style which is executed just before all the actions are applied. The style *must* be cancelled before any "inner" paths (I use the `every path` key here to do this), to avoid infinite recursion.

Ideally the `at end path` stuff would be appended to a macro which would be set to empty at the beginning of every path (i.e., in `\tikz@@command@path` where everything else is reset), and then executed (if non-empty) at the start of `\tikz@finish`.

```
\tikzset{every path/.append style={at end path/.style={}}}
\let\tikz@finish@orig=\tikz@finish
\def\tikz@finish{%
    \tikzset{at end path/.try}%
    \tikz@finish@orig%
}
\tikzset{%
  mypath/.style = {%
    at end path/.style={
        insert path = {%
          \pgfextra{%
            \let\tikz@mode@save=\tikz@mode
            \let\tikz@options@save=\tikz@options%
            \pgfinterruptpath
              % This is the path that should receive the options
              \path \pgfextra{\let\tikz@mode=\tikz@mode@save\let\tikz@options=\tikz@options@save}
                (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
            \endpgfinterruptpath
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. For the record, this won't work if the options are given the other way round (`\fill[mypath,blue]`) but in my use case, it does not matter.